# How to add local tiles to website with leaflet

Tags: html, leaflet

So I just started using html quite a while ago. And a friend asked me to help him build a website. We are currently using OSM tiles. And one problem is he wants it in a different language. So he made the tiles and I want to add the tiles to the webpage locally. In other words, the tiles are on my computer. I'm only able to get 1 tile even though there is like a hundred. How would I be able to get the rest of the tiles

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>A Leaflet map!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet.css"/>
  <script src="leaflet.js"></script>
  <style>
    #map{ height: 100% }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="map"></div>

  <script>

  // initialize the map
  var map = L.map('map').setView([45.8311111,-74.1992559], 16);

  // load a tile layer
  //I want to load multiple tile layers
  L.tileLayer('file://C:/Users/Adam-PC/Documents/Map/Tiles1/18/77027/93433.png',
    {
      attribution: 'Tiles by <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org">Open Street Map</a>, Data by <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org">Open Street Map</a>',
      maxZoom: 17,
      minZoom: 9
    }).addTo(map);

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `'file://C:/Users/Adam-PC/Documents/Map/Tiles1/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'` instead of hard coding the zoom, y and x values in your Tile Layer URL template.

Comment: It still seems not to be working. I get a grey screen. Is it because the tiles are in different folders?

Comment: Yes the URL template must reflect how your tiles are stored / their folder structure. You can use your browser's console to see the resulting URL being called (and possibly resulting in 404 errors)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was able to fix it by changing the zoom value. Keep up the good work :)